# Making tabs right to left with angularUI

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using angularUI to make tabs

```
<tabset>
    <tab
        ng-repeat="t in tabs"
        heading="{{t.heading}}"
        select="go(t.route)"
        active="t.active">
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

I didn't find a way to sort and align the tabs from right to left

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tab alignment is CSS. The default is to float:left the tabs. If you want float:right, just do this:

`.nav-tabs>li {
  float: right;
}`

Answer (score 1):

```
<tabset>
    <tab
        ng-repeat="t in tabs | orderBy:'heading':true"
        heading="{{t.heading}}"
        select="go(t.route)"
        active="t.active">
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

CSS:

```
.nav-tabs > li {
    float: left;
}
```

[Documentation for AngularJS orderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)